# How to start using Google API v3?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, api, google-api

I downloaded and compiled the official **[Google's API for .Net](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/releases)** successul removing some incompatible referenced projects (Mobile WP81 projects).

Now, I'm trying to getting started with my very first steps to use the API, I'm following the **[official examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads)** of Youtube API, the big problem I have is that I can't reproduce the example because these Namespaces are missing ...so I can't import them:

```
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth
Imports Google.Apis.Samples.Helper
Imports Google.Apis.Youtube.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.Data
```

These are the assemblies that I have compiled and referenced in my project:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.dll
Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll
Google.Apis.Core.dll
Google.Apis.dll
Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll
```

Plus these external dependencies:

```
BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll
log4net.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Zlib.Portable.dll
```

What I'm missing?.

### UPDATE

I think that exists two problems, the first is that seems the example is old because the Namespace `Google.Apis.Authentication` seems has changed to `Google.Apis.Auth`, however, I still can't find the equivalent Namespaces for these:

```
Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth
Google.Apis.Samples.Helper
Google.Apis.Youtube.v3
Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.Data
```

And the second problem, seems that I need to download an additional Google's library/dependency to obtain the Youtube API  then be able to see the Youtube Namespaces, I think so, but I don't know where to download.

Comment: I've got something working. I will post here later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: This solution has been tried and tested**

First and foremost I myself did not go to Github to get the API's for `.Net`. One reason and usually has been a problem at least for me is because of trying to figure out dependencies and such. With that in mind I recommend using **NuGet** and use the `Package Manager Console`. The reason is simple, you ***do not*** have to worry about compiling source, reference issue's with other libraries, dependencies etc...

> **How Did I get It To Work?**

Please follow these steps as not only getting the `API` to actually work, but I did find out that there are more issue's with the official example you provided above (***not your fault***). I believe its a change in the newer version, specifically the `YouTubeService` class. Haven't had much time knocking this one down or yet report it to them, but is an issue with `await`and `ExecuteAsync`... Anyway's let get to work.

1. Get a new C# project going at least **4.5**; I did a C# form application. The one you referenced was console, but will still print out information in the `Visual Studio Ouput Window`. Save this project off and run it at least one time; creates the `bin\debug` directory that you need before using the `Package Manager` for `NuGet`.
2. Go to `Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Console`.
3. Once loaded copy and paste: **Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3** and then hit enter to download the package. You will see it download everything and should be good to go. You will notice a new file under your project: **packages.config** which is related to this package, ***do not remove it***. Also here is the link to that `NuGet`, grab it [**HERE**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/)

At this point, just re-build and run your program. Everything should be great to go at this point.

**This end's your actual Issue I have addressed**

Now on to the issue's I came across using the provided (official) example.

1. First you need to get the `client_secrets.json` and you can do that through the [**Developer Console**](https://console.developers.google.com/). Download the `json` file and put it in your `bin\debug` directory. You can worry about placing it elsewhere later...
2. In that example find the code below:

   `// Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
     var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();`

You need to remove: `await` keyword and `ExecuteAsync()` to: `Execute()`. This is the problem I came across and it was a pain in the a$$. It would execute, but I never received a response back, never, never... That was until I removed the listed above and replaced them.

3. There is one more place you need to modify as well. Please see below...

`// Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
          var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();`

You need to do the same for this line as well as I said above. Once done, you should be able to run the application and get result's back.

I hope you find this useful and relieving as much as I did. Also as I mentioned, this isn't reported to Google yet about the `ExecuteAsync` issue. I hope someone reports this so it can be addressed and fixed.

Happy Coding!

**Reference To Await**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm stuck with one of the first steps, when I try to download the Youtube package, I get a Nuget error saying my client version is old... `Install-Package : The 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.7.40911.287'.` I'm under Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I tried to search the Youtube package through the "normal" online NuGet explorer of VS, but I didn't found it.

Comment: Then maybe did you installed some VS2013 updates which maybe updated the NuGet console? could be that. I will search now the available VS2013 updates.

Comment: Go to `Tools --> Extentions & Updates -->` When screen loads look for `Updates` and see if NuGet is listed. If so see if you can update... I do have `2.8.50313.46` installed as well...

Comment: For the interest: Problem solved by installing this updated extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca

Comment: Nice glad you got it!

Comment: Now I have another problem, when I attempt to install it: **Install-Package : Unable to uninstall 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' because 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' depends on it.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3**, in the full installation log it says that the google apis are successfully installed, but in my "packages" dir there is any Google dll, just Microsoft.Bcl related dlls.

Comment: Forget that last comment, I'm stupid and was targetting NetFx4.0 instead 4.5, now installation was done perfect.

Comment: Almost done, about finding the code `var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();`, could you please link the url of what code example are you talking about?

Comment: this?: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#search_by_keyword  I used the navigator searcher but I can't find that comment line, neither that code below. In that case I think Google is showing us different documents, mine has a Spanish description (but english-coded) could you please upload it in pastebin or in your answer?

Comment: No this one https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads it's the same link you put in your question :)

Comment: I'm seeying the same document, the Await keyword doesn't exists in any of that samples. please provide the code to test your steps. (fackin' Google language mechanism) I'm not crazy, this is what I see: http://pastebin.com/QmEWeLqg

Comment: Interesting, I updated answer with an image so you can see what I am seeing :)

Comment: Really I don't have that code, the more similar instruction I have is using the "Fetch" method, could you please share it entirelly in some way to finish the steps? :P because my code-example differs from yours, and you are trying to explain me an example that I don't have, then I still don't know how to perform my first steps with the API. Sorry for all this headache!